# Characterizing the closure of metrizable spaces with monotone sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \tau, \ge)$ be a metrizable totally ordered space and $A \subseteq X$. Then $ x \in \overline{A}$ if and only if there is a monotone converging sequence to $x$.

The idea i’m following is that:

I) as the space is metrizable then $ x \in \overline{A}$ iff there exists a sequence converging to it

II) use the fact that every sequence admits a monotone subsequence to complete.

Is my intuition fine? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fine argument, if you also allow monotone to include (partially) constant, e.g.

Comment: For example if $W$ is linearly ordered by $<_W$ then the lexocographic-order topology  on $W\times \Bbb Z$ is discrete, hence metrizable.  A convergent sequence in  a discrete space is eventually constant.

Comment: Monotonicity is intended here as $x_n \uparrow x$ if $x_1 \precsim x_2 \precsim \dots x_n \precsim \dots $ with $x = \sup_{n}x_n$and so eventually constant is included. Do you think we can relax metrizability of $X$ and keep only the first countability axiom?

Comment: @ShinoIamanaka yes, first countability ( or being a *sequential* space) will give that sequence.